# Select all columns between two other columns with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I was hoping this would return the columns `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, but unfortunately it errors instead. How can I use functional programming to `select` two columns and all the columns between them?

```
iris %>% select(between(Sepal.Width, Petal.Width))
```

Note: actual use case has 1000+ columns so not wishing to manually write column names, nor to `-` out columns (as there are many omitted ones also)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the last n columns of data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017141/select-the-last-n-columns-of-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: @Aramis7d thanks for the suggestion. I was after how to select between two columns (not necessarily the last column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` already does that :

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Width:Petal.Width)
```